Run a workflow on the same branch as the previous workflow (using workflow-run)
I am making some workflows in GitHub Actions. The first workflow (which is triggered manually) triggers the second one on completion.
First workflow:
name: Infrastructure Provisioning

on:
  # Manual trigger
  workflow_dispatch:

  # Trigger on new releases
  release:
    types: [created] # Triggers when a new release is created

jobs:
  terraform-provision:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

    //  ...................... more code

Second workflow:
name: "Ansible: setup docker on machines"

on:
    workflow_run:
        workflows:
            - Infrastructure Provisioning
        types:
            - completed

jobs:
    process-terraform-outputs:
      if: github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success'
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest

      steps:
          # Checkout to the repo
          - name: Checkout repository
            uses: actions/checkout@v4
            with:
              ref: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_branch }}
            // ....................... more code

The thing is that it works fine, the first workflow runs smoothly then calls the second one. But let's say I got 2 branches: main and A
The catch is that let's say I ran the first workflow in branch A, the second one launches on success but in the main branch instead of the A branch.
I tried changing the ref into
ref: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_sha }}

ref: ${{ github.ref }}

but nothing works. So right now for every single tiny thing I want to check, I need to merge the branch into the main then run the workflow from the main branch.

If I understand the question well, the second workflow needs to be run on main branch and not A. One way to achieve is using git checkout in Second workflow like below:
steps:
      - name: Checkout branch
        run: |
          git checkout main

Code Update after below comment:
Without explicitly specifying the ref parameter, the actions/checkout action will use the github.ref context variable.
github.ref usually points to the branch or tag that triggered the workflow.
If no specific branch or tag triggered the workflow (e.g., manual trigger), it will default to the default branch of your repository (usually main).
Per documentation here. You can use ref, and point to specific branch.
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    with:
      ref: <branch-name>

Replace  with the desired branch name (e.g., A,B...).

I am sorry, but that's not quite it. It's actually the opposite.
I am looking for the following:

I launch the First workflow from branch A
if It runs successfully the Second workflow gets also launched in Branch A. The problem is that the  Second workflow launches always on main instead of A


If updated code does not work then may be you can try with step mention earlier. Replace main with A, this will ensure that correct branch is switched.Hope it helps!

I want to automate it. to detect the branch name based on the selected branch in the github ui since we are using workflow_run.
